# Development of Hilbert transform relationship

Tags: fourier-transform, transfer-function, transform, hilbert-transform

In the development of Hilbert transform relationships, Prof. Oppenheim has chosen
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}X_R\left(e^{j\theta}\right)\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(\omega-\theta-2\pi{}k)d\theta
=X_R\left(e^{j\omega}\right)
\end{equation}
in his book "Discrete-Time Signal Processing, 2e" Chapter 11 pp807, Eq. 11-24. I failed to understand how he arrives at it.

Does anybody any idea how has derived, please let me know?

I tried some BUT IT DID NOT GIVE the above relationship:

## 1:

\begin{align*}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}X_R\left(e^{j\theta}\right)
\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(\omega-\theta-2\pi{}k)d\theta&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}X_R\left(e^{j\theta}\right)2\pi\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}
\delta(\omega-\theta-2\pi{}k)d\theta\\&
=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}X_R\left(e^{j\theta}\right)e^{j\theta{}n}d\theta\\&
=x_e(n)
\end{align*}

OR

## 2:

\begin{align*}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}X_R\left(e^{j\theta}\right)
\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(\omega-\theta-2\pi{}k)d\theta&=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}X_R\left(e^{j\theta}\right)
\delta(\omega-\theta-2\pi{}k)d\theta\\&
=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}X_R\left(e^{j(\omega-2\pi{}k)}\right)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second try was already close. However, you treated the integral as if its limits were $-\infty$ and $\infty$. With the given integration limits there is only *one* delta impulse in the integration interval, i.e. only one index of the sum is relevant, all others are outside the integration interval. So if for some given value $\omega$ this index is $k=l$, then the result is

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}X_R\left(e^{j\theta}\right)
\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(\omega-\theta-2\pi{}k)d\theta=X_R(e^{j(\omega-2\pi l)})=X_R(e^{j\omega}\cdot e^{-j2\pi l})=X_R(e^{j\omega})$$

Answer (score 0):

I searched through many books and found this way only yesterday night:
[source: Encyclopedia of Mathematics and its Applications 124: 
Hilbert transforms Vol.1, pp659 Eq.13.122 written by Frederick W. King]
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}X_R\left(e^{j\theta}\right)
\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(\omega-\theta-2\pi{}k)d\theta&
=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\pi+2\pi{}k}^{\pi+2\pi{}k}X_R\left(e^{j(\theta-2\pi{}k)}\right)
\delta\left(\omega-\theta\right)d\theta\\&
=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{(2k-1)\pi}^{(2k+1)\pi}X_R\left(e^{j(\theta-2\pi{}k)}\right)
\delta\left(\omega-\theta\right)d\theta\\&
=\left\{\ldots+\int_{-3\pi}^{-\pi}X_R\left(e^{j(\theta+2\pi{})}\right)
\delta\left(\omega-\theta\right)d\theta\right.\\&
\quad+\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}X_R\left(e^{j\theta}\right)
\delta\left(\omega-\theta\right)d\theta\\&
\quad+\left.\int_{\pi}^{3\pi}X_R\left(e^{j(\theta-2\pi{})}\right)
\delta\left(\omega-\theta\right)d\theta+\ldots\right\}\\&
=X_R\left(e^{j\omega}\right)
\end{align*}

But then, I think a similar logical conclusion given by Matt L. is still required here too.

Comment: Yes, it's the same thing. You need to see that only one of the integrals between the braces is non-zero. Which one depends on $\omega$, but it does not matter because the result of this integral is always the same: $X_R(e^{j\omega})$.

Comment: Absolutely, now I understand fully. I was having difficulty convincing others about this integrals with sum! Phew!! :) Thanks @ Matt L.